# Is it possible (in principle and in meaningful way) to describe any subset of n-dimensional real Euclidean space?

Tags: set-theory, computer-science, real-numbers, machine-learning, neural-networks

Let us start with some background and motivation. My main question is very simple and it is available few paragraphs further and it is written in bold.

My problem is based from the emerging theory of deep learning and one of its most interesting paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.14587 This paper suggests to consider deep neural network layer-wise and to assigned the complex of sets to each layer - this complex consists mainly from the set of possible activities of the neurons of the layer to which this set is assigned.

What this means? It means that layer U can have n neurons and each neuron can have activity level in some real interval, it may be [-1, 1]. So, the set of possible activities of n neurons is the Cartesian product of sets of individual intervals and the resulting set of possible activities is subset of n-dimensional real Euclidean space (vector space).

The approach of this article if generalizing comparing to the usual approach. The usual approach of deep learning (deep neural networks) is to assign one point/vector (n-dimensional vector) to some concept, some value, some decision. It is called the embedding of this concept or value and usually it is point.

The referenced article is open to the generalization and it allows to assign subset of n-dimensional Euclidean space as the representative of the concept. Even more - it goes further. Some theory (crisp or fuzzy) is assigned to each layer U. The theory is the set of statements in some logic. Of course, each theory can have one or more semantic models and usually those models are built using the set and its subsets. This happens in the references article as well. The n-dimensional Euclidean space is the space in which the models for the theory can be built. Each model of each possible theory is the complex of subsets and the usual set operations can be used to model the usual logical connectives.

Of course, this article is very detailed. It considers the following aspects as well:

- It denotes the semantic models/set-systems by F (when considered in the general case) and X (when considered as a set of activations) and it also considers the languages overs the models, denoted by A.
- This article use the full power of category theory: it considers theory and logics from  the categorical perspective which involves the classifying objects of the topos and those classifying objects assign truth values to the objects (of the category of sets).
- This article considers the machine learning of theory from date: learning corresponds to the transformation of theory into more elaborated theory or into more crisp (less fuzzy) theory. Toposic view on logics and theories are used and that is why such transformations could be considered with ease. Otherwise such transformations may seem to be a formidable task.

**Now - we can state the main problem. If we want to make this approach computable (implement on computer), the `we should be ready to describe any possible subset of n-dimensional real Euclidean space (or more specifically: any subset of only the subspace [-1,1]*[-1,1]*...*[-1,1] of real Euclidean space) in some meaningful way`. E.g. it is very easy do describe convex regions, some subspaces that can be defined as points on some algebraic curve, some list of specific points. But my question is: can and how we can describe any subscapce of Euclidean space?**

If we can describe any subset, then we can consider the system of such subsets and posit that such system can be a model for some theory. And then we can try to see in some computational experiments on deep neural networks whether or not exactly such kind of system of subsets emerges in some layer of deep neural networks. Again - this seems to be formidable task (and the companion article https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.04751 is one example), but category theory is the framework i which we can try to manage this task.

**I am afraid, that maybe there are no meaningful tools to express particularly nasty subsets of n-dimensional (finite-dimensional) Euclidean space?**

If we can express any subset of Euclidean set (e.g. as a set of formulas or lists of individual points) then we can also express any system of subsets and that also means that we can express any model for any logic.

Of course, I would be happy to arrive at some finite and compact framework (some calculi), but it may not be possible. I am a bit confused now, but I hope that there are people with enough theory knowledge to give me some illumination about this.

Comment: Try $n=1{}{}{}$.

Comment: OK, I see that there may be subset which consists from infinitely many points. And those points can have no common meaning (e.g. there is no curve or some other concise mathematical object to which they may belong) and that is why the enumeration can be the only tool to express such subset. As the enumeration of infinite sets is not possible with computers, that may mean that may task is unsolvable.

Comment: $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb R^n, [0,1]^n$ have the same cardinality, the bijections are well defined, so they have essentially the same subsets. So cases $n=1$ and $n=1000$ are essentially the same.

Comment: "Infinite" is not the worst. "Very infinite" is a problem.

Comment: But still... Is there some branch of mathematics that consider such totality of subsets? That try to classify them? Or math is considering the sets that are associated with algebraic curves only or some other nice objects, e.g. simplicial sets? Or maybe there are some approximations available? Maybe we can avoid some particularly nasty subsets and the remaining subsets can be represented by some formulas quite well?

Comment: The set theory is considering arbitrary sets.

Comment: Yes, of course, set theory. But we have complete classification of finite simple groups. And mathematicians are considering classifications of other objects as well. Maybe subsets of [-1, 1] can be classified as well? Maybe there is some theory that is trying to do this?

Comment: @TomR You might be looking for [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory). It is classifying definable subsets of the real line according to their complexity.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It seems to be descriptive set theory indeed. And I have found https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.00188 that can easily make connection with toposes. So - I have a way to proceed and study. Of course, I am curious how to handle the sets that are outside the scope of descriptive set theory (e.g. computer science has some hypercomputation efforts as well), but it is topic for other question.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44102/is-the-analysis-as-taught-in-universities-in-fact-the-analysis-of-definable-numb seems to be very relevant

Answer (score 2):

I am imagining that a  "description" is a string over some finite alphabet (symbol set).

If this is the case, it seems the answer to your question is no.

The cardinality of the set of all finite descriptions (finite strings over a finite alphabet) is the same as the cardinality of the natural numbers.

The cardinality of the set of countable descriptions (not that one would necessarily want to allow these) is the same as the cardinality of the real numbers.

However the set of all subsets of the reals (or of $\mathbb{R}^n$) is a greater cardinality. Hence you don't have enough descriptions to cover all subsets of the reals.

Comment: What about second (and higher order) logic/languages? I have heard that second order logic can express the notions which can be expressed only by infinite statements of first order logic.

Comment: This is actually more subtle. You're saying that there is a set of definable subsets of the reals. That's not actually an axiom of any first order theory, because it's inexpressible. There are models of ZFC in which every object is definable.